# Split string and put the extracted string to another new column in python

Tags: python

***My data -***

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['1', 'Electrical and Instrumentation -DI (Supervisor)'], ['2', 'CCM - DI'], 
        ['3', 'Business Development and Marketing - DI'], ['4', 'MDs Office'],
       ['5', 'Administration - PI']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sl_no', 'dept'])
df

sl_no   dept
1       Electrical and Instrumentation -DI (Supervisor)
2       CCM - DI
3       Business Development and Marketing - DI
4       MDs Office
5       Administration - PI
```

So in this data, I need to split **dept** column, and need to create another column where my values should be only **PI** or **DI**. Is it possible to create a code where it accurately takes out only **PI** or **DI** from **dept** column

***My output -***

```
sl_no   dept                                 division
1       Electrical and... -DI (Supervisor)    DI
2       CCM - DI                              DI
3       Business Dev.... - DI                 DI
4       MDs Office                           None
5       Administration - PI                  PI
```

**I have tried -**

```
new = df['dept'].str.split(' - ', expand = True)
df['division'] = new[1]
```

but this doesn't serve the purpose, because **' - '** this dash is not same, somewhere it is occurring like **' -'**, so I have to rework on it, and also I get a few results like - **PI (Supervisor)** so I have to remove **(Supervisor)** part. The data is not same, it varies, I only need **PI** or **DI**. So I need a code in which, wherever it finds **PI** or **DI** , it will extract it and then create a new column where it only stores **PI** and **DI** only. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to just use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["division"] = df["dept"].str.extract(r'\b(DI|PI)\b')
```

For department values not having either `DI` or `PI` in them, the value of `division` would be `NaN`.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted to do, may god bless u